# Is there a way to make an element dependent on another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a portfolio website and having trouble with something. When I hover over an image of a project, the image grows in size, has reduced opacity and a description of the project appears. However, I want to be able to add a link with the description. The problem is when I hover over the link the image returns to it's default state, meaning the image shrinks back, is opaque and the description fades away along with the link.

I have tried restructuring the javascript and css around but haven't gotten any solutions.

JavaScript:

```
const projectNode = (project) => {
    return (
        <div className="Project">
            <div>
                <div className="previewProject">
                    <img className="Project-image" src={project.image} alt="project-images" />
                    <div className="Project-info" >{project.description}<br></br>
                        <a className="project-link" href={project.github}>GITHUB</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

//CSS//

.previewProject {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}

.Project-image {
 opacity: 1.0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=40);
 transition: transform .3s;
 border: solid 3.5px #606060;

 /* Animation */
 margin: 50px auto;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.Project-image+.Project-info {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.Project-image:hover {
 opacity: 0.2;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 transform: scale(1.25);
}

.Project-image:hover+.Project-info {
 opacity: 1;
 color: black;
 }

.Project-info {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 21px;
 width: 25%;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.project-link {
 pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: To make them "dependent", as you put it, put your image in the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation should relate to hovering on the parent `.previewProject`, so something like this:

```css
.previewProject:hover .Project-image {
    /* Do whatever */
}
```

Comment: Just tried this but when I hover over the link still the image goes back to default and the description along with the link fades behind the image.

Comment: @Meraki-Dot check this pen out https://codepen.io/m0o0tasem/pen/gOYBjzK